# Problemas al cargar con NgFor

Tags: angular

en **component.ts**

```
import {AsignaService} from '../../services/asigna.service'; 

import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
import { Cursose } from '../../models/cursose';
import { Sesion } from '../../models/sesion';
import { Registro } from '../../models/registro';
import { Usuario } from '../../models/usuario';
import { Asigna } from '../../models/asigna';


declare var M: any;
var claves:any;


@Component({
  selector: 'app-asigna',
  templateUrl: './asigna.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./asigna.component.scss']
})
export class AsignaComponent implements OnInit {

  public Mensaje;
  public codigo;



  constructor(
    public cursoseService: CursoseService,
    public sesionService: SesionService,
    public usuarioService: UsuarioService,
    public registroService: RegistroService,
    public asignaService: AsignaService,
    public _router: Router) { }



  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCursoses();

  }

addCursose(form?: NgForm){
    if(form.value._id){
      this.asignaService.putAsigna(form.value)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.resetForm(form);

        M.toast({html: 'Información Actualizada'});

      });
    } else {
      this.asignaService.postAsigna(form.value)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.resetForm(form);
        M.toast({html: 'Almacenada la información'});

      });
    }

  }

  getCursoses() {
    this.sesionService.getSesions()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.sesionService.sesions = res as Sesion[];
        console.log(res);
      });
  }

  captura( id: string ) {

    this.sesionService.getSesion( id )
          .subscribe( sesion => sesion = sesion );
          M.toast({html: 'Información capturada'});
       this.codigo = id;
       this.getCursose(this.codigo);
       M.toast({html: this.codigo});
  }

  getCursose(codigo) {

    this.cursoseService.getCursose(codigo)
      .subscribe(res => {

        claves=res;

        console.log(claves);


      });
  }

  resetForm(form?: NgForm) {
    if (form){
      form.reset();
      this.asignaService.selectedAsigna = new Asigna();
    }
  }



}
```

en **html**

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label>Curso</label>
                <select (change)="captura1( $event.target.value )" [(ngModel)]="asignaService.selectedAsigna.cursos" name="cursos" class="form-control" required>
                  <option value="">Seleccione curso</option>
                  <option *ngFor="let clave of claves" [value]="cursoseService.cursoses[clave]._id">
                    {{ clave.cursos }}
                  </option>
                 </select>
              </div>
```

no me carga los datos y no me sale error

[image: imagen]

Comment: Te aseguraste que la `API` te devuelve datos? la propiedad **cursoseService.cursoses** es pública? Que error lanza tu consola?

Comment: no me envia error

Comment: anteriormente me salia un error de array

Comment: pero lo solucione con this.cursoseService.cursoses = this.cursoses;

Comment: me hace el filtro pero no me carga es el combo la informacion

Comment: Hay algo que me causa curiosidad... en tu **service**, tiene esta línea `this.cursoseService.cursoses = this.cursoses;` cuando debería ser `this.cursoseService.cursoses = res;` no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al parecer no tienes claro algunos términos utilizados en `Angular`.

Primero y como te mencione en los comentarios, estas asignando a la variable **this.cursoseService.cursoses** un valor que por lo que veo no trae nada, así que sólo debes cambiar **this.cursoseService.cursoses = this.cursoses**; por **this.cursoseService.cursoses = res**;

Después mencionaste que al cambiar esta línea obtenías el error

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type
>   'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Array

Lo que quiere decir es que estas tratando de iterar un objeto con tu **[ngFor](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)** que sólo permite arreglos para dicha función; trata de hacer algo así y prueba

```
data: any

getCursose(codigo) {        
    this.cursoseService.getCursose(codigo)
       .subscribe(res => {
       this.data = res;
       //this.cursoseService.cursoses = res ;
       console.log(res);
    });
}
```

y en tu **HTML** cambia tu iteración por

```
*ngFor="let cursose of data"
```

Finalmente el error que causaba la anomalía de funcionalidad era porque **claves** es un `objeto` que tenia dentro un `array` llamado **curso** que era el que se debía iterar; además al momento de usar la variable *claves*, esta venía nula. La solución fue agregar el signo de interrogación para que permitiera un valor `null` de esta manera

```
<option *ngFor="let clave of claves?.curso" [value]="clave._id">
   {{ clave.cursos }}
</option>
```

Dio mucha batalla pero se arreglo mediante Skype!!

Saludos

Comment: me sigue saliendo el error anterior

Comment: perdón me falto el **this.data**.. pruebalo así

Comment: así lo probé y no sale

Comment: Y te lanza el mismo error? =/ podrías incluir tu componente **completo**?

Comment: ya ubique la codificación

Comment: Ok.. vi tu codigo y me percate que en el ngOnInit estas llamando a getCursose() ... la pregunta es.. deseas que tu select se cargue apenas este lista la página?

Comment: lo que pasa que con eso llamo a otro y cargo un combo inicial y al escoger una opcion delcombo es que quiero que carge lo otro

Comment: faltará un _as Cursose[]_ en tu res? al igual que lo estás manejando con la línea **this.sesionService.sesions = res as Sesion[];**

Comment: esos cambios ya los hice y me sale el mismo error

Comment: Esto no se puede quedar así.. tienes Slack? Skype? Traté de hablar por chat contigo pero no tienes la reputación suficiente =/

Comment: me podrias ayudar con tu correo electronico

Comment: pauloc1989@hotmail.com, agregame a Skype y seguimos por allá

Comment: Paulo Urbano te felicito solucionaste el problema

Comment: te agradezco por tu tiempo y dedicación

Answer (score 2):

El error que sale es por que `*ngFor` solo recorre elementos iterables como son los arrays. `this.cursoseService.cursoses` es un objeto no iterable.
Te añado una solución.

```
var claves;
getCursose(codigo) {        
    this.cursoseService.getCursose(codigo)
       .subscribe(res => {
       this.cursoseService.cursoses = res ;
       this.claves = Object.keys(this.cursoseService.cursoses);
    });
}
```

Modifica el HTML:

```
<option *ngFor="let clave of claves" [value]="cursoseService.cursoses[clave]._id">
   {{ cursoseService.cursoses[clave].cursos }}
</option>
```

Comment: me filtra pero me sale este error

Comment: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Array

Comment: Asegurate que `this.cursoseService.cursoses` sea realmente un _Array_, me huele a que el array es **cursoseService** y que **cursoses** es un objeto dentro de ese array

Comment: me podrias ayudar con un ejemplo que yo soy nuevo en esto

Comment: Primero... como estas declarando **cursoseService**? podrías incluirlo en tu pregunta?

Comment: constructor(
    public cursoseService: CursoseService,
    public sesionService: SesionService,
    public usuarioService: UsuarioService,
    public registroService: RegistroService,
    public asignaService: AsignaService,
    public _router: Router) { }

Comment: este error me sale como me dejaste en la solucion

Comment: con la  solución que me ubicaste ya no me sale el error del Array pero no carga en el combo

Comment: Lo solucionaste? Si no es así, hace un console.log de  la variable `res` o de `this.cursoseService.cursoses` y pegamelo aqui.

Answer (score 0):

A continuacion dejo un stackblitz con el codigo funcionando. Como se puede ver, no varía de las respuestas ya dadas. Despues de experimentar un poco, llego a la conclusión de que es posible que el json que devuelve esa API no sea válido.

Seria basicamente, lo siguiente:

```
  cursoses: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCursoses().subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.cursoses = res;
      }
    )
  }

  getCursoses() {
    return this.http.get('https://demo4269324.mockable.io/cursoses');
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-116yzn

(El mock que use como API, dura 24 hs. Pero es muy facil de crear uno aqui https://www.mockable.io y reemplazarlo)

Sugiero validar el resultado de la API en esta página: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Responder con solo enlaces se considera de baja calidad; edita esto y coloca lo relevante de los enlaces aquí

Comment: Sigues sin mostrar lo relevante de esos links

Comment: Gracias por el consejo, editado :D